# MySQL INNER JOIN returning all rows

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have two tables 'hotels' and 'flights' that have a 'typeId' field that reference 'itineraries' table foreign key 'id'. 
For example:       hotel.foreign('tripId').references('id').inTable('itineraries');

I want to select all rows from each table that have an itinerary id of 3. I tried the following but I am receiving all ids in itinerary, not just 3.

```
SELECT itineraries.* , hotels.* , flights.* 
FROM itineraries 
INNER JOIN hotels ON hotels.tripId = itineraries.id 
INNER JOIN flights ON flights.tripIid = 3
```

Comment: For every intineraries JOIN hotels... you add all rows from flights where tripIid=3,that`s a cartesian JOIN not an INNNER one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manage the inner join for flights too and filter by where for tripIid =3

```
SELECT itineraries.* , hotels.* , flights.* 
FROM itineraries 
INNER JOIN hotels ON hotels.tripId = itineraries.id 
INNER JOIN flights ON flights.tripIid = itineraries.id 
WHERE  flights.tripIid = 3
```

for you last comment

> How can i edit this so that it still returns all rows if there is a
>   hotel with matching tripID but no flights?

you should use left join

```
SELECT itineraries.* , hotels.* , flights.* 
FROM itineraries 
INNER JOIN hotels ON hotels.tripId = itineraries.id 
LEFT JOIN flights ON flights.tripIid = itineraries.id 
WHERE  hotels.tripId = 3
```

Comment: Thank you !! This worked! How can i edit this so that it still returns all rows if there is a hotel with matching tripID but no flights?

Comment: Why you are changed  the acceteped answer .. is the same and i answered for first  .. is not fair

Comment: That was an accident sorry -- i fixed it

Comment: thanks .. explain better your previous comment .. is not clear what do you want ..

Comment: I have update the asnwer   .. think that left join is what you need .

Comment: I am going to add more tables in addition to hotels & flights (cars, trains, etc..) and I want to search for all tripIDs that have an itinerary ID of 3. However, if there are hotel, flights, and cars that have a matching ID but no traiins, how do I still return the hotels, flights, and cars? When i use this query it does not return anything if train ID is not matching

Comment: In StackOverflow the rule is for a question by time .. i suggest you of post a new proper question  with you new goal .. eventually comment me the link for the new question ..

Answer (score 0):

You query should be:

```
SELECT itineraries.* , hotels.* , flights.* 
FROM itineraries 
INNER JOIN hotels ON hotels.tripId = itineraries.id 
INNER JOIN flights ON flights.tripId=itineraries.Id 
Where flights.TripId= 3
```

In your original you were restricting flights. TripId to be equal to 3, but no constraint (nor direct neither indirect) on hotels and itineraries.  That's why you were seeing all the trip ids